# Incrementation after return

Tags: c++

I think it is a very simple question... I've some code like this:

```
//head is somewhere initialized with 0 (int head=0;)
char testclass::read() {
    return data[head];
    ++head;
}
```

When I try to run it I create a loop. Changing it to:

```
char testclass::read() {
    ++head;
    return data[head];
}
```

runs without a problem, except that head is incremented to fast. So what's the problem?

Comment: `return` returns from the function. Anything after that won't happen.

Comment: What do you mean head is incremented too fast?  It increments once each time you call the function.

Comment: What do you mean when you try to run it you create a loop?

Comment: I wonder why the question was downvoted. The fact that StackOverflow is an English website does not mean all its users speak English as a mother language. And "to fast" was clearly understandable from the context: too early. Anyway I upvoted it to compensate. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
return data[head++];
```

In your first solution `++head` after the return is dead code. Never runs, it's probably thrown away already in compile time. In your second solution, `head`'s been already incremented by the time you return. Too early.

The post-increment `++` operator increments the value sometimes after the evaluation of the `head++` expression and before the semicolon. But the exact time is undefined and compiler-dependent. Therefore never use multiple `x++` expressions within the same statement.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to this answer, btw I was not the downvoter.

Comment: The description of post-inc, while suitable for the OP, is not accurate. The term `head++` as an eval-expression essentially means take the current value of head, remember it, increment head, then use the original value as the eval result. In other words, head *is* incremented before `data` is subscripted, but it isn't `head`s value that is being used for the subscript. it is the value of head *prior* to the increment. This is trivially demonstrable with a function call and a global variable used as the increment op.

Comment: Post-increment does not increment "after the evaluation of `head++`". This is probably one of the most widespread and dangerous misconceptions about pre- and post- sequencing. The key point about the `head++` is that it evaluates to the old, original value of `head`. That's all we know and that's all we need to know. At what point the actual increment happens - before, after, somewhere in the middle - no one knows and it does not really matter.

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding here, as we both state the same thing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
return data[head++];
```

because the behavior of returning a post-incremented variable is defined. The

```
int foo() { return x++; }
```

is equivalent to:

```
int foo()
{
  int temp = x;
  ++x;
  return temp;
}
```

in your example:

```
return data[head++];
```

would be the same as:

```
{
  int temp = head;
  ++head;
  return data[temp];
}
```

Comment: +1 for the behavioral example of post-inc. You'd probably not be surprised how many *professors* aren't aware it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
char testclass::read() {
    char result = data[head];
    ++head;
    return result;
}
```

but as SzG said, this can be abbreviated to `return data[head++];`

Answer (score 0):

First, your need to know [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i).

In your case, you want to:

1. read your `data` at `head`
2. move your `head`
3. return the value read in 1.

So, in code it looks like that:

```
char testclass::read() {
    char result = data[head];     // 1
    head += 1;                    // 2
    return result;                // 3
}
```

Now, you can use `++head` or `head++` instead of `head += 1` here. It won't change the behaviour of your function because the result of this statement is not used (i.e. you *can* do `x = y += 1;` but probably *don't want* to.)

If you want, you can make write this function in one line, but will lose in **readability** (it's often better to have only one statement by line, it's less error-prone this way):

```
return data[head++];
```

This works because `head++` increment the variable but return its "old" value.

But don't think it's faster that the three-line code: your compiler is clever enough to optimize that and will most probably generate the same assembly code for both implementation.

---

Regarding your first version of the function, don't forget that code after a return statement are not executed. (See for example this SO [Execution of code in a function after the return statement has been accessed in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763182/execution-of-code-in-a-function-after-the-return-statement-has-been-accessed-in))